# How to join an element which is in an array which is also an part of another array for best performance in couchbase?

Tags: couchbase, sql++

Below is the sample document for organization

```
{
"org": {
  "id": "org_2_1084",
  "organizationId": 1084,
  "organizationName": "ABC",
  "organizationRoles": [
    {
    "addressAssociations": [
        {
         "activeDate": "2019-08-03T18:52:00.857Z",
          "addressAssocTypeId": -2,
          "addressId": 100,
          "ownershipStatus": 1,
          "srvAddressStatus": 1
        },
        {
          "activeDate": "2019-08-03T18:52:00.857Z",
          "addressAssocTypeId": -2,
          "addressId": 105,
          "ownershipStatus": 1,
          "srvAddressStatus": 1
        }
      ],
      "name": "NLUZ",
      "organizationRoleId": 893,
      "roleSpecId": -104,
      "statusId": 1,
      "statusLastChangedDate": "2019-08-04T13:14:44.616Z"
    },
    {
      "addressAssociations": [
        {
          "activeDate": "2019-08-03T18:52:00.857Z",
          "addressAssocTypeId": -2,
          "addressId": 582,
          "ownershipStatus": 1,
          "srvAddressStatus": 1
        },
        {
          "activeDate": "2019-08-03T18:52:00.857Z",
          "addressAssocTypeId": -2,
          "addressId": 603,
          "ownershipStatus": 1,
          "srvAddressStatus": 1
        }
      ],
      "name": "TXR",
      "organizationRoleId": 894,
      "partyRoleAssocs": [
        {
          "partyRoleAssocId": "512"
        }
      ],
      "roleSpecId": -103,
      "statusId": 1,
      "statusLastChangedDate": "2019-08-04T13:14:44.616Z"
    },
```

}
and below is the sample document for address

```
{
        "address": {
            "address1": "string",
            "address2": "string",
            "addressId": "1531",
            "changeWho": "string",
            "city": "string",
            "fxGeocode": "string",
            "houseNumber": "string",
            "id": "1531",
            "isActive": true,
            "postalCode": "string",
            "state": "string",
            "streetName": "string",
            "tenantId": "2",
            "type": "address",
            "zip": "string"
        }
    }
```

In an organization there are multiple organizationRoles and in an organizationRole there are multiple addressAssociations.Each addressAssociation contains an addressId and corresponding to this addressId 
address is stored in address document.

Now i have to get organizationRole name, organizationRole id, city, zip from the two documents.
What should be the best way to approach this situation for the best performance in couchbase?

I am thinking about using join but not able to come up with an exact query for this scenario.
I have tried the below query but its not working.

```
select * 
from 'contact' As A UNNEST 'contact'.organizationRoles as Roles
UNNEST Roles.addressAssociations address
Join 'contact' As B
on address.addressID=B.addressID
where  A.type="organization" and B.type="address";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in the right direction.

In addressAssociations the addressId is number, In address addressId is string. string and number not same and no implicit type casting. You must fix data or do explicit type casting using TOSTRING(), TONUMBER() etc...

Also N1QL field names are case-sensitive your query using addressID vs addressId (in the document)

```
SELECT r.name AS organizationRoleName, r.organizationRoleId, a.city, a.zip
FROM contact AS c
UNNEST c.organizationRoles AS r
UNNEST r.addressAssociations AS aa
jOIN contact AS a
ON aa.addressId = a.addressId
WHERE  c.type = "organization" AND a.type = "address";

CREATE INDEX ix1 ON contact(addressId, city, zip) WHERE type = "address";
```

Check out https://blog.couchbase.com/ansi-join-support-n1ql/

Comment: will this be a good approach to take cache all the documents with type organisation and then apply the join?